# Unable to properly install Eclipse in Mac OS X Mavericks

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I'm now at my wit's end with this and really struggling.

I've installed both JDK 7.0 and 8.0, I've tried both 32bit and 64bit versions of the Eclipse software and I've installed Java 1.6 from the Apple website. I've also restarted my machine and tried this whole process on a new user on my laptop.

Before I did some of this I was getting the error message 13 which I discovered was to do with some sort of incompatibility. It was asking me to install JVM 1.6 which I think I did.

I'm now getting a message that "Eclipse has unexpectedly had to quit" every time I've opened it.

I've been looking at [this blog](http://medievalcode.com/blog/2013/08/29/osx-mavericks-you-need-a-java-6-runtime-to-run-x-error-dialog-fix/) came up and when I looked I didn't have the JavaVM.Framework folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple JREs installed, Eclipse could be picking up an incompatible one. First, ensure that you match 32-bit/64-bit of Eclipse and the JRE you want to use. If one is 32-bit and the other is 64-bit, Eclipse will not start. Next, edit your eclipse.ini file and add the following two lines at the very beginning of the file to force Eclipse to use a particular JRE.

```
-vm
[full-path-to-JRE's-bin-folder-or-java-executable]
```

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal window and execute this command:

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

This should return a list of all the installed version of Java, something along the lines of:

```
1.7.0_67, x86_64:   "Java SE 7" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home
1.6.0_65-b14-466.1, x86_64: "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
1.6.0_65-b14-466.1, i386:   "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Then to set your `JAVA_HOME` run this command (obviously set it to the version you want to use):

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7
```